# Probably cannot pass a "driver" as a parameter in stepdefs class

Tags: java, selenium, constructor, cucumber, pageobjects

So i got a problem with running my test framewrok written in cucumber (i would say im just starting). 
Here is the code https://github.com/nokedajunky/cucumber2

When i run "Register.feature" file it fails with:

```
Error:(13, 55) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable driver
  location: class stepdefs.RegisterStepDefs
```

I'm what is wrong with "RegesterStepDefs" class where im initializing LandingPage object - i cannot pass "driver" as a parameter. It seems like an error which i cannot handle for a long time. 
Any suggestions appreciated

*BasePageObjectSetUp class in package pages;*

```
public class BasePageObjectSetUp {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public BasePageObjectSetUp(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

*LandingPage class in package pages;*

```
public class LandingPage extends BasePageObjectSetUp {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//@[//div[contains(@class,'menu-body')]//span[contains(text(),'Logowanie')]]")
    private WebElement buttonLogowanie;

    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@class=register-wrapper]")
    private WebElement buttonRejestracja;


    // calling the inherited construtor from PageObject class
    public LandingPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }


    public void clickButtonRejestracja() throws InterruptedException {
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonRejestracja));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        buttonRejestracja.click();
    }
}
```

*LandingPage class in package stepdefs;*

```
public class BaseSetUp {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        //Disable geo localization popup
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://www.vozilla.pl");
    }

    @After
    public void cleanCookies() {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

*RegisterStepDefs class in package stepdefs;*

```
public class RegisterStepDefs {

    private LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver); **<<<< I got a problem here**

    @Given("^User navigates to the register page one$")
    public void userNavigatesToTheRegisterPageOne() throws InterruptedException {
        landingPage.clickButtonRejestracja();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: Specifically, note that #1 in the off-topic list mentions that "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: While it's fine to include links to off-site code for reference purposes, your question needs to be answerable on its own merits, without requiring people to follow those links.

Comment: Bit too much work to type it all out but you should use dependency injection. Cucumber supports it